# Docker: Error response from daemon: failed to create endpoint priceless_noether on network bridge:

Tags: docker, ubuntu, server, arm

I'm running an ubuntu server 21.10 on RasberryPi4.Docker version 20.10.7, build 20.10.7 0ubuntu5. I tried `docker prune` and to reinstall docker fully and even reinstall ubuntu, but nothing seems to work. Whenever I try to run the sample hello-world image I get: `Docker: Error response from daemon: failed to create endpoint priceless_noether on network bridge:: failed to add the host (veth4cfcda9) <=> sandbox (vethda57bc9) pair interfaces: operation not supported.ERRO[0000] error waiting for container: context canceled`

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The vent kernel module is not installed.  If you do: sudo apt install linux-modules-extra-raspi

This will install the module and docker will work.

from: https://www.mail-archive.com/ubuntu-bugs@lists.ubuntu.com/msg5968593.html

Comment: Great, that solved it!

Comment: Today, I got the error `E: Unable to locate package linux-modules-extra-raspi`. OS is based on `bullseye`.

Comment: For me, a restart was required but this worked!

Comment: Using Pi and stuck at same error with docker. This comment solve my problem. Thanks Omniver

Answer (score 6):

For the **Raspberry Pi** in particular, this was solved just rebooting.

Apparently, this happens because `apt upgrade` prepared a new kernel and deleted the old one (while running). This means the Pi continues to run, but you can not load new modules on the kernel. Rebooting solves it by starting the upgraded kernel.

Answer (score 1):

Restarting docker daemon worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Restarting the Docker service  resolves resource allocation issues
`sudo systemctl restart docker`